# Join on project number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to join two tables based on a project number. In the table 'dbo.transactions' projectNR has a prefix (e.g. **111**0001'), but not in the 'dbo.Projects' table (e.g. 0001).

```
SELECT a.projectNR, b.Description FROM dbo.transactions a 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Projects b
ON a.ProjectNR = b.ProjectNr
```

The a.ProjectNR (1110001) should join on b.ProjectNR. I tried to use STUFF to strip the first 3 numbers, but I don't know how to mix this in a inner join:

```
Stuff(a.projectNR, 1, 3, '')
```

Comment: Can u test this  `ON Stuff(a.projectNR, 1, 3, '') = b.ProjectNr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.projectNR, b.Description 
FROM dbo.transactions a 
  RIGHT JOIN dbo.Projects b ON Stuff(a.projectNR, 1, 3, '') = b.ProjectNr
```

Keep in mind that this is the absolute worst thing you can do, this won't use any indices at all. Once either table reaches a large size, you'll bog down your system waiting on this query.

You might have better luck with the following:

```
SELECT a.projectNR, b.Description 
FROM (select *, Stuff(a.projectNR, 1, 3, '') normalprojectnr from dbo.transactions) a 
  RIGHT JOIN dbo.Projects b ON normalprojectnr = b.ProjectNr
```

But it still won't use any indices. If this grows large enough, I would first select `transactions` into a temporary table with the extra column, apply an index on it manually, and then do the join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.projectNR, b.Description FROM dbo.transactions a 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Projects b
ON Stuff(a.projectNR, 1, 3, '') = b.ProjectNr
```

OR

```
SELECT a.projectNR, b.Description FROM dbo.transactions a 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Projects b
ON a.ProjectNR = '111'+cast(b.ProjectNr as varchar(10))
```